# XRotor blade angle distribution

Tags: propeller, blade

My question is about the XRotor definition of the blade angle distribution (beta), which XRotor solves for or requires as input. Is the blade angle on XRotor defined as the angle between the rotation plane and the chord line of the blade section (geometric pitch angle) or is it defined as the angle between the rotation plane and the zero-lift line of the blade section?

Comment: This is a question about a particular software application, not about aviation in general. Better to see what support the software publisher makes available.

Comment: The normal definition of the blade pitch angle is between the rotation plane and the chordline of the blade section. It's a geometrical feature (so not dependent on the lift of the blade).

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it is relative to the foil chord line.

You should be able to do some tests to confirm this.